# Multiple upload laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, upload

I have a problem with storing the files I upload into my database table.
This is my code of the view:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ArticleController@store', 'method' => 'post' )) !!}

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1">
    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Titre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='title' id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Saisir titre">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
        <label for="videourl">Video URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="video_link" class="form-control" id="videourl" placeholder="Saisir url..">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
        <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple="multiple" >
    </div>
   <div class="form-group m-b-20">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea class="summernote" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Enregistrer et publier</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light">Annuler</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and this is the code of my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Article::create($request->all());

    $article = New Article();
    $article->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
    $article->title = $request->get('title');
    $article->description = $request->get('description');
    $article->save();

    if($request->hasFile('files')):
        foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) :
            $path = '../articles/uploads';
            $titre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($path, $titre);
            $fichier = New Articlefile();
            $fichier->article_id = $article->id;
            $fichier->title = $title;
            $fichier->path = $path;
            $fichier->save();

        endforeach;

    endif;

    return redirect('articles');
}
```

Comment: Ok? What *exactly* is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i can't upload the file.the table of the files in the database is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your opening line should allow the operation, so try

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ArticleController@store', 'method' => 'post','files'=>'true' )) !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm not fully understand your issue but I've found you're lacking`enctype="multipart/form-data"` attr in the  tag.

Or Laravel using : `Form::open('url', array('files'=> true))`